# Adding Second Light Switch in Bathroom for Lights

Tags: wiring, lighting, bathroom, recessed-lighting, install

We have in our bathroom one light switch, which controls the bathroom fan and LED lights. The bathroom fan has power and works perfectly however, we installed new wire and connected them with the LED lights (separate cable to the right in image). We would like to add a second separated switch to it.

Currently the orange and yellow wires are connected with a light switch and it works but we are not quite sure how we would wire the separate cable to a new switch so that we can turn on/off the LED lights separately from the bathroom fan. Pretty sure the cable for the LED lights need to be connected to the orange/yellow cable. Thank you for helping us out.

[image]

Comment: How did you connect the new cable to the led lights? Did you remove the existing feed to the lights and just connect the new cable to the lights?

Comment: FYI, wires are individual conductors. Cables are bundled groups of them. Let's get our terminology correct for clarity. :) Please revise further as needed.

Comment: Judging by the wire colors, the steel box, and the lack of visible sheathing in the box, I'm guessing that you have conduit. It may be required where you live for fire protection. If so, a new circuit using just cable may not meet code. Please tell us about that in your question.

Comment: Your photo is not showing any orange or yellow cables/wires. You should label the wires in the photo like you did other things.  Your photo also does not show clearly which wire is connected to which.

Comment: @kreemoweet The lower wire to switch looks orange to me. I also don't see any obvious yellow wire.

Comment: it will be orange or yellow, try them both. One will be always on, one will be switched. When you find the always-on, pigtail it to the new switch and run the other lead to the LED. If i had to bet, i would say that you'll be connecting both black wires together and both white wires together.